# Optimizing nested coordinate transformation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm working on an implementation of an Evolutionary Algorithm in Pandas using Numpy. The code is based around an implementation found on [MathWorks](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35801-evolution-strategies-es?tab=discussions). It works and produces logical results, however it is incredibely slow.

The 'Pythonized' version of this code looks something like this:

```py
# Initialize
xm = np.zeros((n, nlambda))
        sigmam, alpham = list(np.ones(nlambda) * np.nan), list(np.ones(nlambda) * np.nan)
sigmam: List[np.ndarray]  # list of NUMBER OF OFFSPRINGS np arrays 264x264
alpham: List[np.ndarray]  # list of NUMBER OF OFFSPRINGS np arrays 264x264

for i in population_size:
   ### Some code ###

   alpham[i] = np.where(alpham[i] > math.pi, alpham[i] - 2 * math.pi, alpham[i])
   alpham[i] = np.where(alpham[i] < -math.pi, alpham[i] + 2 * math.pi, alpham[i])
   R = np.eye(n)
   for m in range(n - 1):
      for q in range(m + 1, n):
         T = np.eye(n)
         T[np.ix_([m, q], [m, q])] = [[np.cos(alpham[i][m,m]), -np.sin(alpham[i][m,q])], [np.sin(alpham[i][q,m]), np.cos(alpham[i][q,q])]]
         R[:, [m, q]] = np.dot(R, T[:, [m,q]])
    ### Some code ###
```

We are looking for methods to optimize this code, by making more clever use of numpy arrays/vectorization. What would be ways to optimize this?

Comment: is `alpham` pre-computed or is it computed in `###  Some code  ###`

Comment: @DanielF, alpham is currently computed in `### Some Code ###`:

`alpham[i] = np.where(alpham[i] > math.pi, alpham[i] - 2 * math.pi, alpham[i])
alpham[i] = np.where(alpham[i] < -math.pi, alpham[i] + 2 * math.pi, alpham[i])`

Comment: @DanielF also changed the code in the question.

Comment: take a look at `numba` package